# Sitecore - Installation Database Server

Tags: sql-server-2012, installation, server, sitecore, sitecore7

Trying to install Sitecore 7.1 on local machine but getting an error while attempting to connect to SQL Server. If I browse for a Database Server nothing comes up in the list. I have SQL Server 2012 installed and several databases that were created from Visual Studio. What am I missing to make the connection?

Comment: Just type the server, or a dot for local SQL server. you don't need the browse.

Comment: (local)\SQLEXPRESS is the default listing doesnt work I've also tried the actual name of my local server, which is different

Comment: @leflis Can you confirm how you browse for a database server? And share you database connection strings minus credentials of course.

Comment: after some more troubleshooting. I was able to install. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For some it may be a case of the SQL Server Service has stopped running. To turn it back on:

1. Open up Sql Server Configuration Manager.
2. Select SQL Server Services in the tree view on the left
3. In the Context Window on the right check to see if your SQL server service is turned off.
4. If it is right click and click start.

[image]

Comment: I checked that, its running

Comment: @leflis Ah check sql browser service is running by going to services.msc. It might be disabled right click on service go properties and drop down saying disabled change to automatic and then start the service. Its role is to help you find instances it might help.

Comment: I pulled the summary.txt file from the install and its says 64bit. Product features discovered: SQL Server 2008 and SQLEXPRESS for the Instance

Comment: Started SQL Server Browser in services setting and tried to install but no luck